# Pulling information from a database into checkbox value

Tags: php, html, database, forms, checkbox

I have a website where users upload information into a database via form. I also have an update page where users can edit and update information they have already put on the database. The update page is virtually identical to the upload page. The main difference is that is has information from the database as values.

Now a section of this form is checkboxes. I am currently trying to extract the information from the database for the checkbox fields.

Here is what I have right now.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="utilities[]" value="Television" <?php if ($varUtilities == 'Television') echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>Television
<input type="checkbox" name="utilities[]" value="Internet"<?php if ($varUtilities == 'Internet') echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>Internet
<input type="checkbox" name="utilities[]" value="Electricity (hydro)"<?php if ($varUtilities == 'Electricity (hydro)') echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>Electricity(hydro)
<input type="checkbox" name="utilities[]" value="Gas"<?php if ($varUtilities == 'Gas') echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>Gas
```

Works fine if you only choose one checkbox

Problem: What if you check two or all of them. When I upload the check box I upload as an array. How do I adjust this so It can read the array and pick up "Television" from [Television, Internet, Gas] or Pick up "Gas" from [Television, Internet, Gas]

Comment: create a value array of `$varUtilities` and use `in_array('Gas', $varUtilities);` to check

Comment: I see what you mean now for the array of $varUtilities it seems I need to change that so it would be `array("Televison", "Gas", "Internet")` Because as of right now it is out putting as "Television, Gas, Internet". How do I change it to be exactly like `array("Televison", "Gas", "Internet")`

Comment: you need to build it out of your database or what ever storage system your retrieving it from